# Webhook vs Http request in logic apps

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

New to azure and webhooks..I'm struggling to understand whether I should use a webhook or HTTP request in my logic app, I've been looking into webhooks but it's not clear to me yet.

My first bit of logic will be the following:
Record updated in dynamics -> POST to http or webhook to api -> api does x with that record data and returns a primitive immediately

My second logic path:
Listener gets update -> POST with http/webhook to logic app -> does x with body

Would I be correct that just using http is best for both flows? What are the strengths for the webhook over http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Webhook` is just **HTTP Post** callback to any URL. As Webhook works on HTTP protocol with POST method, if you are always going to use POST method for your logic app, Webhook could be used.

Looking at the workflows you mentioned, in my opinion, Webhook is a good choice.

1. [Webhooks W3C](https://w3c.github.io/w3c-api/webhooks)